# Is it possible to append a string in an statement if the value is not null in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So say I have something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname, " " IFNULL(mname, ""), lname) FROM name
```

how would I add a space to that statement if mname is not null? Nothing i've tried has worked and I'm kind of lost.
Obviously I can do something like

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname, " " IFNULL(mname, ""), " " lname) FROM name
```

but then that gives me two spaces instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another `CONCAT` in the middle name:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname, 
              IF(mname is null, "", CONCAT(" ", mname)), 
              " " lname) 
  FROM name
```

Comment: Mistakenly I changed the order in the inner concatenation, but corrected.

Comment: yeha was waiting for the time limit to fade.